# Date filter not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I created a new datetime row for a page, it works well. The column displays all the specific dates, but when I want to show specific rows using a date filter, it doesn't display a thing.

In the model:

```
 before_validation :payment_date

 def payment_date
  self.payment_date = sales_order.payment_transactions.last.date
 end
```

The date filter from the controller file:

```
   filter :payment_date, :as => :date_range, :collection => proc { Complaint.all.map{|c| c.sales_order.try(:payment_transactions).try(:last).try(:date)} }
```

I suppose I did a couple of mistakes and i'm curious where the bad coding is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AA filtering is based on Ransack, so your filter would look as follows (assuming `sales_order` is an association on your model):

```
filter :sales_order_payment_transactions_date, label: 'Some label', as: :date_range
```

Here you basically go along the association chain - it is acceptable with ransack.